# Generate a bimetallic surface in ASE

Tags: density-functional-theory, surfaces, atomic-simulation-environment

I am trying to generate a 50-50 Pt-Au fcc(111) bimetallic surface in ASE for DFT calcualtions. However, I am unable to figure out the procedure. Any help regarding the procedure will be great. Thanks

Comment: Even the same 50-50 composition can have different chemical orderings. What ordering do you want? Or you just want a random bimetallic surface structure with 50-50 composition? Whether you want a random ordering or a typical L1$_0$/L1$_2$ ordering, I can write an ASE script for you.

Answer (score 1):

First you can generate a pure host metal surface slab using `ase.build`, for example a 2x2x3 Pt(111) slab. Here you can directly insert the lattice parameter for your target alloy surface, e.g. 3.9 Å:

```
from ase.build import fcc111

atoms = fcc111('Pt', (2,2,3), a=3.9, vacuum=5.)
```

Then can change half of the atoms into dopant atoms by visualizing the structure and note down the atom indices that you want to change to the dopant metal. For example, the dopant indices for a typical L1$_0$-ordered surface are

```
dopant_ids = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

You can then change the Pt atoms with those indices to Au by

```
for i, atom in enumerate(atoms):
    if i in dopant_ids:
        atom.symbol = 'Au'
```

In the comment you said you want a 10x10x3 slab, you can simply expand the cell by

```
atoms *= (5, 5, 1)
```

Now you get the 10x10x3 L1$_0$-ordered Pt$_{0.5}$Au$_{0.5}$(111) surface structure:

```
from ase.visualize import view

view(atoms)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Shaun Han, thank you so much for your comment. I would really like to understand a bit deeper about L10 and L12 orderings, what's the difference between them and a random bimetallic surface, and how to identify the dopant ids. I want to have a surface with (10x10) in xy-direction, with 3 layers along z direction

Comment: @ARKAPRAVASARKAR For L10 and L12 orderings, the two metals distribute in an ordered way, which forms a very stable structures with 1:1 and 3:1 compositions, respectively. Random ordering means the two metals randomly distribute. If you want to generate a 10x10x3 surface, just do `atoms = fcc111('Pt', (10,10,3), vacuum=5.)`

Comment: Thank you @Shaun Han. How does the dopant ids change then? Also, it will be great if you can provide some references for L10 and L12 orderings

Comment: Why not use ACAT (Alloy Catalysis Automated Toolkit)?, I've been using it and it is a great package ;)

Comment: @Okano can you please help me with the script to build the surface I want?

Comment: @ARKAPRAVASARKAR I have updated the answer. I was thinking about suggesting you to use ACAT, but since you asked to do it in ASE, here you go.

Comment: Thanks @ShaunHan. My concern is, by replacing Au with the original Pt atoms, it will change the lattice parameter as well right? So we need to include the lattice parameters as well when generating the structure

Comment: @ARKAPRAVASARKAR No. Replacing host metal with dopant metal will not change lattice parameter. You can directly specify the lattice parameter when generating the clean surface. I have edited the answer again. You can accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks @ShaunHan for the answer. Please do recommend some reference for the L10 and L12 ordering of the surfaces. it will be helpful for me in the future.

Comment: @ARKAPRAVASARKAR [This paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.61.3317) for example.

Comment: Thanks @ShaunHan the structure looks good for my calculations

Comment: Hi @ShaunHan can you also let me know what changes should I make in the script in order to generate a L10 75-25 Pt-Au 111 surface?

Comment: @ARKAPRAVASARKAR L10 is for 50-50, L12 is for 75-25. The only thing you need to change is the `dopant_ids`, which you should be able to inspect by yourself

Comment: @ShaunHan I searched quite a lot, still couldn't figure out the dopant ids for L12 ordering

Comment: @ARKAPRAVASARKAR Why are you searching? You need to visualize it in ASE and figure it out by yourself

Comment: @ShaunHan okay. Thank you.

Comment: @ShaunHan Hello. You helped me earlier with this doubt. From this code, I built the bimetallic surface which is orthogonal (keeping the orthogonal = True keyword on). After that, I performed a geometry optimization of the surface, but I see that the top layer Au atoms are moving away from the surface. I am completely out of ideas regarding this one. Can you please help me in understanding why the atoms are moving away from the surface? I am performing the geometry optimization in CP2K